# Wire the homepage so that it fires off a Push notification message to my iPhone every time someone lands on the page

Tags: javascript, iphone, curl, scripting, push-notification

I looking for a simple way to wire the homepage of my website so that it fires off a Push notification message to my iPhone every time someone lands on the page (just visiting in their browser). I'm aware this could become annoying!

I currently send regular notifications to my iPhone using cron and curl to check sites / RSS feeds for change and then fire to to the Prowl API who in turn send it to my iPhone - like so:

```
curl https://prowl.weks.net/publicapi/add -F apikey=$apikey -F priority=$priority -F application="$app" -F event="$eventname" -F description="$description"
```

Could I do something similar from with the HTML of the homepage - call a script on my server which in turn fires a similar curl request above? Maybe with Javascript or PHP? Ideally I'd like the loading and rendering of me webpage to be uninterrupted by the call.

Hat tip to Prowl - http://prowl.weks.net/api.php and to flx.me
Both of which I use to make what I have already working.

Comment: You'd definitely want to do this from the server and not from the page. If you put the code in the page, then visitors to your site would be able to see your key information.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the command directly from PHP if you have PHP's cURL library installed (see http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php and http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/):

```
<?php
// This is at the top of the HTML page
// (although you could put it anywhere)
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://prowl.weks.net/publicapi/add");
// The next 2 commands assume that you are sending a POST request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "apikey=$apikey,priority=$priority&application=$app&event=$eventname&description=$description");
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
?>
<html>
...
```

Additionally, you could use PHP's [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), or similar function to execute the cURL command:

```
<?php
// This is at the top of the HTML page
// (although you could put it anywhere)
exec('curl https://prowl.weks.net/publicapi/add -F apikey=$apikey -F priority=$priority -F application="$app" -F event="$eventname" -F description="$description"');
?>
<html>
...
```